# Camel test: how to get access to the headers set in the route

Tags: unit-testing, apache-camel

I have a Camel Unit Test and I want to get access to the header values that are set on the Exchange on the first point in the route.

Route example :

```
<route id="VCM001_incoming">
    <from uri="file:{{InLocation}}"/>
    <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
    <setHeader headerName="FileNameWithoutExtension">
        <simple>${file:onlyname.noext}</simple>
    </setHeader>
    <to uri="direct:splitFile"/>
</route>
```

Java code where it's used :

```
public List<String> createList(Exchange exchange) {
    String fileName = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("FileNameWithoutExtension");
```

So all good to this point.

Now in my test I want to find out what header value is "FileNameWithoutExtension".

```
@Produce(uri = "file:{{InLocation}}")
private ProducerTemplate inputEndpoint;

@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:output1")
private MockEndpoint outputEndpointRPR;

@Test
public void testCamelRoute() throws Exception {
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("file:{{OutLocation}}").to(outputEndpoint);
        }

    inputEndpoint.sendBody("test-message");

        Object[] expectedBodies = new Object[]{"Success: filename=xxx"};
        // At this point I need the header 'FileNameWithoutExtension' to setup the correct 'expectedBodies'

    outputEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceivedInAnyOrder(expectedBodies);

        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get it quite easily using:

```
outputEndpoint.getExchanges().get(0).getIn().getHeader("FileNameWithoutExtension");
```

Answer (score 7):

Know this is very late, for camel 2.15.2 you can use the following

```
outputEndpoint.expectedHeaderReceived("header", "value");
```

Answer (score 1):

Look in the mock endpoint. There should store in memory each received exchange so you can do something like:

```
outputEndpointRPR.getExchanges().get(0).getIn().getHeader("FileNameWithoutExtension");
```

See http://camel.apache.org/mock.html

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to verify a header is by doing:

```
outputEndpoint.expectedMessagecount(1);
outputEndpoint.message(0).header("header").isEqualTo("value");
        
inputEndpoint.sendBody(body);
 
outputEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
```

Note: you should do this in the setup of your test! Putting the endpoint at the bottom will lead to false positives of your test.